# Toggle the following selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of elements like that

```
<h4>Question</h4>
<h5>Answer</h5>
<h4>Question2</h4>
<h5>Answer2/h5>
```

where I hide the answers by

```
h5{
display:none;
}
```

and display them again by

```
$( "h4" ).click(function() {
  $( "h5" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

Of course that just toggles ALL h5-elements by clikcing ANY h4 and not the exactly following one. Therefore my question: How can I trigger the next following selector of a given species (like "h5" in that particular example).

Something like $(this > "h5" ).slideToggle(...  didn't work out. But could that be sort of a solution?

Comment: `$( "h4" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next("h5").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
$("h4").click(function() { 
   $(this).next("h5").toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the h5 elements id's.

```js
$(function() {
  $("h5").toggle();

  $("h4").click(function(e) {
    var answerSelector = '#' + $(this).data('answer-id');
    $(answerSelector).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 data-answer-id="a1">Question</h4>
<h5 id="a1">Answer</h5>
<h4 data-answer-id="a2">Question2</h4>
<h5 id="a2">Answer2</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following for the first child

```
$("h4").click(function() {
  $(this).children("h5:first-child").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     ...
  });
});
```

Or just this for all children h5 of the h4 element that was clicked.

```
$("h4").click(function() {
  $(this).children("h5").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     ...
  });
});
```